# How to trigger a jenkins build from Servlet

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup jenkin and create a jenkins job to build my maven project, every thing is working fine, now I want to trigger this build when user click on button on my web app, is it possible to do, if so please let me know any sample or links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger builds using HTTP, is that ok for you?

In the job configuration, under Build Triggers section, there is checkbox "Trigger builds remotely", where you can specify token for the build, and find the URL to load in order to trigger the build with that token.

You can also use this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API